# JQuery-ui timepicker multiple intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, timepicker

Is it possible to have the JQuery-UI timepicker to show multiple intervals?
Or at least to have one interval bat make some of the elements disabled?

For example from 9AM -> 11AM and from 17PM to 19PM.

Currently I can only have one interval with minTime and maxTime:

```
timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i',  'forceRoundTime': true, 'scrollDefault': 'now', 'minTime': myStartHour,
            'maxTime': myEndHour});
```

Thing is I'm really bound to this jQuery-UI timepicker, and cannot use another plugin.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, use the **disabledTimeIntervals** to disable specific intervals in between:

```
 ('.timepicker').datetimepicker({'disabledTimeIntervals': ['8:30',...
```